# nginx reverse proxy to access a backend webcam server that requires 2 ports for the URL

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use NGINX as a HTTPS to HTTP reverse proxy for old webcams that don't support SSL.  The prblem webcam require 2 ports, one is for web access & the other is for its video feed.  I need to include both ports to connect and see the video stream.

However, the PROXY_PASS directive only seems to allow only one port per LOCATION.  I tried to enter two lines with same URL but different ports.  It does not like that and won't restart the nginx service.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have another webcam that only uses one port and it works fine.

Rich

Comment: Can you write your configuration file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration file

Proxy pass server for your first port

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#ssl configuration begin
ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
keepalive_timeout    70;
#ssl configuration end

#proxy pass
proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.7:70/url$request_uri;//70 is your first port
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        Request_Uri_X $request_uri;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;


}
Proxy pass server for your second port
server {
listen       81;
server_name  localhost;

#ssl configuration begin
ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
keepalive_timeout    70;
#ssl configuration end

#proxy pass
proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.7:71/url$request_uri;// 71 is your second port
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        Request_Uri_X $request_uri;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;

}
```